# PHP search function through multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing a search function, which needs to query 4 tables.

- Users
- Types
- Subtypes
- Services Offered

I need to run a search through the `users` table, which queries the `types`, `subtypes` and `services offered` based on the respective `id` in the users table.

For example:

A row in the users table may be like this:

```
| id | type | subtype | services_offered | first_name | last_name | contact | company |
| 1  |  1   |    2    |        47        | Gareth     | Davies    | g@g.com | Gazza   |
```

A row in the types table may be like this:

```
| id |   type  |
| 1  | finance |
```

And so on...

I've got it sort of working, but for some reason it returns about 30 rows for each contact! Here is my SQL.

```
SELECT
    c.type, c.subtype, c.first_name, c.last_name, c.company, c.contact, c.services_provided, c.additional_information, c.date_updated,  t.id, t.type, s.id, s.subtype, so.id, so.services_offered 
FROM 
    contacts c, types t, subtypes s, services_offered so 
WHERE 
    ((c.type LIKE '%$q%' || c.subtype LIKE '%$q%' || c.first_name LIKE '%$q%' || c.last_name LIKE '%$q%' || c.company LIKE '%$q%' || c.services_provided LIKE '%$q%' || c.contact LIKE '%$q%' || c.additional_information LIKE '%$q%' || t.type LIKE '%$q%' || s.subtype LIKE '%$q%' || so.services_offered LIKE '%$q%') 
    AND (c.type = t.id || c.subtype = s.id || c.services_provided = so.id))
```

Ideally it would only return one of each contact!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

A reasonable guess would be that you need to group the results, so use

```
 GROUP BY c.id
```

in the end of the query would probably do it

Comment: @daviesgo Great it worked! Please mark the question as resolved!